# .jsp website not loading behind new Cisco ASA 5510

Tags: web-server, cisco-asa

I have an internal web server hosting a few different websites.  I'm switching from a Sonicwall NSA to a Cisco ASA appliance.  When I switch over to the ASA all of my websites load for external hosts EXCEPT one login page that ends in .jsp

Other elements of the page load but the login, password, and submit elements don't.  I figure the ASA (with CSC Trend Micro Module) must be filtering or hindering access somehow but I can't seem to figure it out.  Any suggestions?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok turns out .JSP Javaserver Pages requires port 81 traffic to also be forwarded in order to work.  Small detail overlooked, just passing the info along.